# Error Deploying my Node JS App to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

My code runs well locally but when I run on heroku, I see the error:

> at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mystrelle.herokuapp.com request_id=5874d970-4178-4f51-ad38-62d510d8a047 fwd="197.211.56.97" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

```js
var skype = require('botbuilder');
var express = require('express');
var app =  express();

var botService = new skype.ChatConnector({
 appId: 'da026eab-b762-4ff6-9f01-191d70e37437',
 appPassword: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'   //// i hid the pass
});

var bot = new skype.UniversalBot(botService);



bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
 // body...
 if(session.message.text.toLowerCase().indexOf('hi')>=0){
  session.send('Hi ' + session.message.user.name +
  ' thank you for your message: '+session.message.text);
 }else{
  session.send('Sorry I dont understand you.........');
 }
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 // body...
 res.send('skypeBot listening......');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
 // body...
 console.log('skypeBot listening......');
});
```

Comment: Add `package.json` to the question, this may help.

Comment: {
  "name": "skypebot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Skype HR Bot",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "hr",
    "bot"
  ],
  "author": "Nurudeen Amedu",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "botbuilder": "^3.11.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}